# Remove padding between cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: red">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div style="background-color: green;">1111<br /><img src="http://i.imgur.com/45IxCbL.png"  class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div  style="background-color: blue">222<br /><img src="http://i.imgur.com/45IxCbL.png"  class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div style="background-color: yellow">333<br /><img src="http://i.imgur.com/45IxCbL.png"  class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div style="background-color: orange;">444<br /><img src="http://i.imgur.com/45IxCbL.png"  class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/t814cmts/10/

I would like remove padding between cols, so I add to css:

```
.container div.col-xs-3 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

This working ok, but I would like also add padding or margin to first (111 - padding/margin-left) and last element (444 - padding/margin-right).
So I added simply margins for childrens:

https://jsfiddle.net/t814cmts/11/

But now first and last elements are smaller than the second and third.

How can I the best way to make margin/padding only for first and last elements without using px?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Can you show what do you want?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan please check https://jsfiddle.net/t814cmts/11/ . In this example box with 222 and 333 are larger than 111 and 444. I would like to have all boxes equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the padding to the row and not the columns

```
.container div.row {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.container div.col-xs-3 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s3j3mywz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px"` to `div.row`.

Here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxbyoupq/)

Or you can wrap your `col-xs-3` divs in to another div and set above style.